# Fill ListView items in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

It seems to work for everyone but not for me. I want to fill ListView items horizontally when my window is bigger then stack panel with items. I have the following .xaml

```
    <ListView x:Name="comboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ArticleCategories}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedArticleCategory}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="Azure" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" ></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="abc" Width="Auto"></Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Here is what I have
[image]

Comment: It's unclear what your actual question is. Do you want the items to evenly fill the StackPanel, or just the last item fill the remaning space?

Comment: I want the items evenly fill the StackPanel

Comment: @AshotKhachatryan evenly fill if window is bigger. What if window is smaller?

Comment: @Clemens Thanks a lot it worked.

Comment: @dkozl It will add scroll view like in case UniformGrid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a `UniformGrid` with a single row as `ItemsPanel`:

```
<ListView ...>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="abc"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```